# PHP setcookie won't work

Tags: php, cookies

I am completely baffled by this problem. Setting a cookie should be the easiest thing in the world, but for whatever reason it's just not working. Currently I'm just trying to get a test-script to work. It looks like this:

```
    $cookie_name = "user";
    $cookie_value = "John Doe";

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 86400 * 30, "/");
    setcookie("act", "sj", time() + 86400 * 365);
    setcookie("bbba", "Hello", time() + 86400);

    echo $_COOKIE['act'];
    echo $_COOKIE['bbba'];
    echo $_COOKIE['user'];
```

None of these cookies will set. Nothing will echo, and I can not find the cookies when using the inspector. I've tried the following:
- Placing the echo $_COOKIE in another file in the same directory.
- With and without ob_start() and ob_flush()
- Using "/", "/direcotry" and nothing at all as path
- Moving the file to the root directory to see if it works there.

Nothing seems to work, and I cannot see what could possibly be wrong. Other scripts using cookies are working on the same domain - which is located on a web hotel.

Can anyone see the problem here?

Comment: Is any other output being sent to the browser before this code, even a stray line break or whitespace character?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, EatPeanutButter. It was a whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

It's from php manual. You can set the value in $_COOKIE array by manual if you really want it in same page which's declared.

```
$_COOKIE['key'] = 'value';
echo $_COOKIE['key'];
```

[PHP Manual setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: My first thought, too, but giving the OP the benefit of a doubt when he says, `I've tried the following: - Placing the echo $_COOKIE in another file...`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by whitespace at the beginning of the document.